# error using a method from a class on a second parameter of map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with a string(User) and a list of books for each user

```
std::map<std::string,std::list<Book>> app;
 app.insert(std::make_pair(Friend1,borrowedBooks));
app.insert(std::make_pair(Friend2,bookFr));
```

In class Book i have an atribute named BookRating

```
class Book{
private :

    int bookRating_;
public:
    int getRating(){ return bookRating_;}
```

And i am trying to display all the books(from every user) that have a 5 star rating and i did this

```
auto it=app.begin();
    while(it != app.end()){
        if((it->second).getRating()==5){
            print(app);
        }
        it++;
    }
```

Where print func looks like this :

```
void print(std::map<std::string,std::list<Book>> m){
    for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();++it){
        std::cout<<"["<<it->first<<","  <<it->second<<"]"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have an error that sound like this :

```
 error: 'class std::__cxx11::list<Book>' has no member named 'getRating'
         if((it->second).getRating()==5){
                         ^
```

So the problem is with getRating and i dont know why so i hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

`it -> second` is a list of books not a book. You have to iterate over `it -> second` and get the rating of each book on its own.

Comment: And how to do this?